# CASE returning true incorrectly

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SELECT CASE WHEN expression schematically the same to the below:

```
SELECT TelephoneNumber,
  CASE WHEN TelephoneNumber IN
    (
     SELECT TelephoneNumber
     FROM ....
    )
  THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS CheckCol
FROM Table1
;
```

I would expect to get a list of numbers in the column `TelephoneNumber` and a corresponding `True` or `False` string in the column `CheckCol` if the number exists in the sub-select.

Instead what I end up with is `True`, even if the `TelephoneNumber` isn't returned in the sub-select.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I have since identified the problem. I was missing an inner join within the sub-query which meant it was in fact returning everything, even though I didn't think it should have been.

Comment: Your query runs fine for me (although I wouldn't write it like that).  Here is a condensed example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39ebc0/1

Comment: In your real code are you using table aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a query with a proper join in the FROM clause instead. Use an outer join and then check on null

```
SELECT Table1.TelephoneNumber,
   CASE WHEN Table2.TelephoneNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 
        'True' ELSE 'False' 
   END AS CheckCol
FROM Table1 
    left outer join Table2 
    ON Table1.TelephoneNumber = Table2.TelephoneNumber
```

---

See the comment below, *if* `Table2` contains multiple entries for the same `TelephoneNumber` value then you should add `Distinct` after the `SELECT` to avoid returning duplicate values in the result set.

---

Same query but using the "old" join syntax where tables are identified in the `FROM` and the join in the `WHERE` clause. I believe the `(+)` is in the correct end of the relationship.

```
SELECT Table1.TelephoneNumber,
   CASE WHEN Table2.TelephoneNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 
        'True' ELSE 'False' 
   END AS CheckCol
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.TelephoneNumber = Table2.TelephoneNumber(+)
```

Comment: Just a note, this might need `distinct` to return the correct results.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I'd like to try this, but I'm more familiar with using an outer join like this:

`SELECT * FROM
Table1 a, Table2 b, Table3 c
WHERE a.TelephoneNumber = b.TelephoneNumber(+)
AND a.TelephoneNumber = c.TelephoneNumber(+)`

How would I translate that into ANSI style?

Comment: @WillC - the join syntax above is ANSI compliant (ANSI-92 SQL). It is also preferred over the "old" style joins where tables are specified in the `FROM` and the join occurs in the `WHERE`. It is also easier to read. Is there a reason you would prefer to use the "old" syntax (maybe dealing with an old version of Oracle)? If so let me know, I will update the answer with a version that uses the "old" syntax (sorry, can't think of a better name at the moment than "old").

Comment: I've since discovered that the problem was a missing join within my sub-query which meant it did return everything when it was nested, but not when I ran it separately for testing.

It's a bit hard to explain but unfortunately I can't show my actual code online.

Comment: @WillC - one more reason to define `JOIN'`s in the `FROM` IMO. It should also be more performant because now the lookup only has to occur once instead of for each tuple being returned in TABLE1 (although maybe the query optimizer figures that out and uses a similar/same execution plan).

Comment: @Igor Only that I learnt using the old style (e.g. (+)) and find ANSI style harder to work with when joining multiple tables. One table is fine but doing two or three, as I often do, the code is almost triple the length making it less readable IMO.

I should probably familiarize myself with ANSI style though.

Comment: @WillC - I made an attempt at it, forgive me if the `(+)` is not on the correct side.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want `exists` :

```
select t1.TelephoneNumber, (case when exists (select 1 
                                              from table2 t2 
                                              where t1.TelephoneNumber = t2.TelephoneNumber
                                             )    
                                 then 'Yes' else 'No'
                            end) as CheckCol
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh. This isn't the exact answer, but it did lead me to investigate my joins and I realised within my sub-query I was missing a join, which meant my sub-query was in fact returning everything when I didn't think it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

This would occur if `TelephoneNumber` where not actually in the subquery.  You should *always* qualify column names.  Try this:

```
SELECT t1.TelephoneNumber,
       (CASE WHEN t1.TelephoneNumber IN (SELECT t2.TelephoneNumber
                                         FROM table2 t2 . . .
                                        )
             THEN 'True'
             ELSE 'False' 
        END) AS CheckCol
FROM Table1 t1;
```

My guess is that this will return an error, because `TelephoneNumber` is not in any of the tables in the subquery.